# How to open an element as popup only to a certain precentage of the users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, math

I have a js which is integrated into other websites. When the user enters the site, a function is called from the script and an element pops up.
Is it possible for me, in the js function that pops-up the element, to make it open only for a certain percentage (let's say 60%) of the users? 
I thought about using the `Math.random()` function, but i'm not sure how to make it.

EDIT:
After thinking about it, it might be that this is not achievable by javascript alone and it will require the use of some kind of tracking of users (via database or such). If someone knows of a different way, I'll be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easily achievable by Javascript, and it's very simple!

```
var pctg = 60; // Set percentage here
var rndm = Math.ceil(Math.Random() * 100);

if (rndm <= pctg) {
    // Execute popup statement(s)
}
```

On a first glance, this code snippet gives a `60%` chance that the popup will occur: that is, one page view is completely independent from another page view. It can easily happen that 20 or more subsequent visitors get the popup, but the opposite is also possible. But the more visitors, the closer the `60%` will be approached.

If you want to be mercillesly accurate, you can say 'set the percentage that a given visitor will receive the popup'.

This method will not attempt any kind of balance, it relies purely on sheer number of page views. Also, do not forget, that this is ***per page view***.

If you want to remember whether or not a certain user should receive popups between visits, you can use cookies:

`document.cookie="bShowPopup=0";` or `document.cookie="bShowPopup=1";`

This also opens up the possibility to create a more powerful code, one that creates a given chance of displaying the popup per page view, up until the point that the popup has already been displayed once:

First a function to read and write the specified cookie string:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Please check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for more information regarding the use of cookies.

Next we could do this:

```
// See if the user already received the popup
// The if statement will only evaluate to true if the popup is *not* explicitly disabled (that is, it is set to 1, or not set)
if (getCookie('bShowPopup') !== '0')
{
    var pctg = 60; // Set percentage here
    var rndm = Math.ceil(Math.Random() * 100);

    if (rndm <= pctg) {
        // Execute popup statement(s)
        //stmt123....

        // Set cookie bShowPopup to 0 (so the user won't receive popups ever again)
        // NOTE: The cookie will expire after 30 days.
        setCookie('bShowPopup', '0', 30);
    }
}
```

Another approach, that will create the closest result without any server-side programming or user-tracking is to check whether a certain user should be shown popups only once, and then store the decision result in a cookie. The only thing to modify in the previous code is to set the `bShowPopup` cookie to 0 even if the popup wasn't shown.

```
if (getCookie('bShowPopup') !== '0')
{
    var pctg = 60; // Set percentage here
    var rndm = Math.ceil(Math.Random() * 100);

    if (rndm <= pctg) {
        // Execute popup statement(s)
        //stmt123....
    }

    setCookie('bShowPopup', '0', 30);
}
```

Please, also refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp regarding the use and return valies of Math.random().

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me a lot, combined with a bit of server side code I had to add anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.Random()` is a good choice for this.  `Math.Random()` generates a number between 0 and 1, so if you want a random number between 0 and 10, multiply the result by 10, then take the ceiling of that number to remove the decimal places and convert it to a round number.  For 0 to 100, multiply it by 100.  At the beginning of your pop-up function, add the following:

`var rand = Math.Random() * 100;`

next wrap the code that displays the popup in an if statement that checks to see if the random number you generated is less than or equal to 60:

```
if(Math.ceil(rand) <= 60) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How `Math.Random()` will give assurance of certain percentage ? If `Math.Random()` always return value less than 60 then all users(100%) can see the pop up and there is no chance for certain percentage i think.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of what I did when I needed this functionality

The following code would be a bit easier to maintain if you change the number of options or the chance percentage.

```
var contentId, random = Math.random();

if (random < 0.5) {
  // option 1: chance 0.0–0.499...
  contentId = 0;
} else (random < 0.75) {
  // option 2: chance 0.50—0.7499...
  contentId = 1;
} else {
  // option 3: chance 0.75–0.99...
  contentId = 2;
}

loadContent(contentId);
```

**EDIT** *Based on comment feedback.*

Glad to help. If this is a php page then you don't need ajax. Simply update/return the count at the top of the page via php/sql and then `echo` that figure into your JS function. You only need to check whether the figure is divisible by `3`. If it is then run your popup function. This way you can also report on the amount of times the popup would have been activated.

Comment: The problem is if I have 100 users entering the page, and I get random < 0.5 for 100 times then I just displayed the popup to 100% of users...

Comment: Unless you are storing this data within a database so that you can choose to show depend on what visitor count it is, you won't achieve what you wish. Javascript will not have a way of "knowing" if it has already displayed this page for the last "x" amount of users. If this was done via ajax and php then you would have the stats saved and therefore you could make a simple accurate calculation.

Comment: I think this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I was unsure whether this is possible with javascript alone, and now I know I must use my database in order to achieve this. Thanks!